# SDL Tridion Documentation for ASP.net MVC c#

Tags: dd4t, sdl-tridion

I am looking for SDL Tridion documentation for ASP.net MVC c# integration.

Where they explain the services used by Tridion and their page, components, templates, and content life cycle. Also the DD4T details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find official Tridion Sites documentation on following link https://docs.rws.com/publications/Tridion%20Sites/

And DD4T information can be found on following links https://dd4t.org/ and https://github.com/dd4t